# Is there a situation where MySQL creates a nonclustered index automatically?

Tags: mysql, index

MySQL creates a clustered index automatically when I create a primary key.

But is there a situation where MySQL creates a nonclustered index automatically?

Comment: *MySQL creates a clustered index automatically when I create a primary key.* No, it creates clustered index always. If there is no PRIMARY index, first UNIQUE is used. If it abcent too, internal hidden record number is used. *is there a situation where MySQL creates a nonclustered index automatically?* No when you mean table index.

Comment: ^ looks good enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

- The `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key; it is also "clustered". (Note: Clustered)
- In the absence of an explicit PK, the 'first' `UNIQUE` key containing only non-NULL column(s) is effectively promoted to be the PK.
- If that fails, a *hidden* 6-byte number is used for the PK.
- A `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`, plus a uniqueness constraint. (Note: may be clustered)
- An `INDEX` is a BTree that is used for efficient access.
- A `FOREIGN` key creates an `INDEX` if there is not already a suitable index. (Note: Non-clustered)

The 3 "Notes" are implicitly-created indexes, but not necessarily non-clustered.